# Is there any way to compress test cases?

Tags: python

Let's say I have code like this:

```
if something == 0:
    return something
if something_else = x:
    return something_else
```

And to not make mess here let's say I have 10 more of this `if`s. Do I have to do it like this or there is faster and less messy method? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary is the answer

```
conditions = {
      key1: value1,
      key2: value2,
    }
```

Values may be even reference to functions, and your answer is

```
my_value = conditions[my_key]
```